# How do you counter Lina mid?

Tags: dota-2

I faced Lina mid for the first time with Pudge and was amazed at how strong she is in mid. Her early nukes are absolutely devastating.

My question is how do you counter her early game in mid so she will be crippled late game ?

Comment: Lina isn't a carry.

Comment: @Kotsu Carries carry, but any hero *can* carry.

Comment: Lina is not a hard carry, but she can definitely semi carry with the right items late game.

Comment: Are you kidding? Pudge should defeat Lina easily. If you can't do that, don't play as Pudge.

Comment: @BlaXpirit If it's easy can you explain how? That would answer his question.

Comment: Beating Lina... First and foremost, you need to get magic armor. Lina isn't a carry, but then again neither is pudge. Both are effective gankers though and can wreck the carries in other lanes with well timed ganks.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: It was only at the beginning that I had problems, I had no problems killing lina after the laning phase. It was just a pain for early farming.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Lina crushes Pudge mid, not even a contest.

Comment: It's worth noting that Lina has ridiculous attack range, better than sniper (before he gets 2 points in take aim (as of 2/5/15)), and if she has points into fiery soul, she has some terrifying attack speed. While she is a caster, something that Pudge laughs at when he has flesh heap stacks, she can definitely work as a right-click hero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pudge and Lina both have similar goals as solo mid heroes as they can both snowball into midgame powerhouses easily. However, if they fail to score any kills, they become rather weak.

Neither hero is going to be able to gank too effectively prior to level 6, and so their focus is to get experience as quickly as possible. Lina's only job is to not get hooked by Pudge, and Pudge's only job is to not die. This means that Lina will be getting a majority of the last hits and harassing effectively.

Pudge should be forcing the Lina to stay in a good position for the entirety of the laning phase: his opportunities will come during rune races or when Lina does something dumb. Regarding rune races, this is where the matchup is most volatile. Both heroes should be picking up a quick Bottle, and Lina with her ability to dominate the matchup should also have rather quick Boots. Her best option is to nuke down the wave at about 1:45, 3:45, 5:45, etc. and force Pudge to skip experience to contest runes. By doing this, she can force the Pudge to take risks if he wants to have any say in the lane.

However, the Lina also has a choice: she can attempt to gank sidelanes, or she can continue to keep the Pudge weak mid. If she leaves to gank (obviously call attention to the miss immediately), the Pudge should be using that time to pick up much needed gold. After he hits level 6, he can start moving around the map constantly and leave mid to others who can use the opportunity.

Pudge is all about momentum. A skilled Lina will shut that down at the beginning of the game by not being in a position to get hooked, but she can't control your roaming. Pudge can really take advantage of the night time (between minutes 6 and 12, 18 and 24, 30 and 36, etc.) to land hooks  on opponents who can't even see him. As long as you don't die repeatedly in mid, that opportunity remains open to you.

Comment: good answer. i would recommend skilling flesh heap at lvl 4 if the harassment via bottle crowing/arcane boots gets to much. maybe you can add that to you answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, you have Pudge who has the potential to be a monster at close ranged combat. Note, your strength is her (Lina's) weakness and vice-versa.

So what you need to do early game, is close the distance between her and you. If you try to run away from her, that works to her advantage.

As Pudge, you need to get up close either through different entry points in the lane (if in Mid lane, there are nice little entry points through the jungle and the points where the runes spawn. Remember to use your hook ability to latch on to Lina and grab her where you are standing, free of creeps. Just keep one thing in mind, you need to overwhelm.

Since you are mid, grab a bottle and keep bottling runes. I believe you can find a good rune bottling Pudge build.

Comment: I disagree with what you said about "closing the gap between her and you" for a few reasons. Pudge's priority in the mid lane is first and foremost to get levels so he can start ganking ASAP. I'm guessing BlueTrin's problem is actually getting too close to Lina early on and getting harassed out of lane because of her cheap nukes and the fact that he is a slow melee hero and she's ranged. If you just stay out of her attack range, get EXP, and grab runes when you can, your team contribution at that point is determined on how well you or the Lina perform in your roles (support/gank/roamers).

Comment: yea, and late game pudge should absolutely wreck lina due to his magic resistance

Comment: yea I had no problems at all after laning, pudge is a monster at ganking after you get your early levels.